# jQuery Mobile - Datepicker value in html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, html-table, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code for datepicker which is taking today's date by default but the user is free to change it.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
        //var datepicker = 
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
        } );
    </script>
```

My question is whether I can read the value within the datepicker (either the default or whether the user opted to change it) and display it in an HTML table similar to the below:

'table'...

'th' Date: '$datepicker1' '/th'

...'/table'

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```js
function showDate(value) {
    var columnHeader = $("#myTable").find('th span');
    $(columnHeader[0]).html(value);
    $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>");
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        showDate(dateText);
    }
  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy");
  var today = new Date(Date.now());
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", today);
  var dateFormat = $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat");
  var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  var dateText = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, date);
  showDate(dateText);
});

/*
 * jQuery Mobile: jQuery UI Datepicker Monkey Patch
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html
 */
(function() {
  // use a jQuery Mobile icon on trigger button
  $.datepicker._triggerClass += " ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all";
  // replace jQuery UI CSS classes with jQuery Mobile CSS classes in the generated HTML
  $.datepicker._generateHTML_old = $.datepicker._generateHTML;
  $.datepicker._generateHTML = function(inst) {
    return $("<div></div>").html(this._generateHTML_old(inst))
      .find(".ui-datepicker-header").removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix").addClass("ui-bar-inherit").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-prev").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-next").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext").end()
      .find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e, .ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w").replaceWith(function() {
        return this.childNodes;
      }).end()
      .find("span.ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-btn").end()
      .find("a.ui-state-default.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-priority-secondary ui-state-active").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-active").end()
      .find("a.ui-state-default").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-priority-secondary").addClass("ui-btn").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane").removeClass("ui-widget-content").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-current").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini").end()
      .find(".ui-datepicker-close").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-priority-primary").addClass("ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini").end()
      .html();
  };
  // replace jQuery UI CSS classes with jQuery Mobile CSS classes on the datepicker div, unbind mouseover and mouseout events on the datepicker div
  $.datepicker._newInst_old = $.datepicker._newInst;
  $.datepicker._newInst = function(target, inline) {
    var inst = this._newInst_old(target, inline);
    if (inst.dpDiv.hasClass("ui-widget")) {
      inst.dpDiv.removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix").addClass(inline ? "ui-content" : "ui-content ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-a").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
    }
    return inst;
  };
})();
```

```css
/*
 * jQuery Mobile: jQuery UI Datepicker Monkey Patch
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html
 */

.ui-datepicker {
  display: none;
}


/* set height and left/right margin to accomodate prev/next icons */

.ui-datepicker-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.3125em 2.0625em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker-header .ui-btn {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}


/* fixed width layout for calendar; cells are fixed width */

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  line-height: 2;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-btn {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.ui-datepicker-today .ui-btn {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over .ui-btn {
  border-color: inherit !important;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-btn {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-btn:last-child {
  float: right;
}


/* class that can be added to datepicker <input> element's wrapper; makes room for trigger button */

.dp-input-button-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}

.dp-input-button-wrap .ui-btn {
  top: 0.1875em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Pick a date</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form>
        <input name="date" id="datepicker">
      </form>
    </div>
    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date:&nbsp;<span></span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code provided. Is there any other way the date can be echoed to a label (maybe easier than the example above) even if I had to get rid of the datepicker and get the current date?

Comment: @srajsu: don't worry, it is easy: the relevant code is just in the few rows inside `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1"`. All the remaining code is to provide a full working example with the jQuery UI datepicker inside a jQuery Mobile page. Simply take it as-is and reuse it every time you need a stub for a JQM app with a datepicker!

Comment: @srajsu: i added a sample code how to show the initial today's date and to get the selected date from the datepicker.